# Adding score stops the game swift in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am working on a "Don't Tap the White Tiles" game as a tutorial for some people, and the game works fine until I start adding score. I cannot understand what is wrong, and I think it's actually a problem with Swift. I have a function called ScoreFunc() which holds all of the code for the score (I'll be adding more about the highscore later.) This function is called anytime one of the BlackTiles are pressed (As shown by the Action Outlet "FirstDown()"). I can delete "Score += 1," and it will work fine, or I can also delete "ScoreLabel.text = "(Score)." When they are both in function, it counts the score, but none of the tiles move down.

```
@IBOutlet weak var BlackTile1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var BlackTile2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var BlackTile3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var BlackTile4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var BlackTile5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var ScoreLabel: UILabel!

var Score = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ScoreLabel.text = "0"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
func BlackHawkDown() {
    WhiteTile1.center.y = WhiteTile1.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile2.center.y = WhiteTile2.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile3.center.y = WhiteTile3.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile4.center.y = WhiteTile4.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile5.center.y = WhiteTile5.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile6.center.y = WhiteTile6.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile7.center.y = WhiteTile7.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile8.center.y = WhiteTile8.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile9.center.y = WhiteTile9.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile10.center.y = WhiteTile10.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile11.center.y = WhiteTile11.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile12.center.y = WhiteTile12.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile13.center.y = WhiteTile13.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile14.center.y = WhiteTile14.center.y + 142
    WhiteTile15.center.y = WhiteTile15.center.y + 142

    BlackTile1.center.y = BlackTile1.center.y + 142
    BlackTile2.center.y = BlackTile2.center.y + 142
    BlackTile3.center.y = BlackTile3.center.y + 142
    BlackTile4.center.y = BlackTile4.center.y + 142
    BlackTile5.center.y = BlackTile5.center.y + 142

    if (BlackTile1.center.y >= 600){
        BlackTile1.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile1.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile2.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile3.center.y = -71
        RandomPlacementOne()
    }
    if (BlackTile2.center.y >= 600){
        BlackTile2.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile4.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile5.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile6.center.y = -71
        RandomPlacementTwo()
    }
    if (BlackTile3.center.y >= 600){
        BlackTile3.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile7.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile8.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile9.center.y = -71
        RandomPlacementThree()
    }
    if (BlackTile4.center.y >= 600){
        BlackTile4.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile10.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile11.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile12.center.y = -71
        RandomPlacementFour()
    }
    if (BlackTile5.center.y >= 600){
        BlackTile5.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile13.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile14.center.y = -71
        WhiteTile15.center.y = -71
        RandomPlacementFive()
    }
}
func ScoreFunc() {
    Score += 1
    ScoreLabel.text = "\(Score)"
}
@IBAction func FirstDown(sender: AnyObject) {
    BlackHawkDown()
    ScoreFunc()
}
@IBAction func SecondDown(sender: AnyObject) {
    BlackHawkDown()
    ScoreFunc()
}
```

Comment: I don't know why your tiles aren't moving, but, you are resetting score to zero every time you call `BlackHawkDown()` and have you heard of arrays?  You should read about them!  Is their code that runs the timer to move everything? Or is it only supposed to move on a tap?  Have you set breakpointz to see what is/isn't happening?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have used arrays a lot, this instance would not be too good to use them. :) Also, the Score = Int() should've been put at the top, and I did that in my project too, but I did it differently in StackOverflow.com for some reason. Had to go do something, so I didn't have time to edit the question.

Comment: @Paulw11 There is not timer that runs the code, it is just when you tap a button, it runs the code. I have set breakpoints, and the source of the error is the mixture of Score += 1 and ScoreLabel.text = "\(Score)". I have tried pretty much every way to run this project, and the score will just not work for some reason. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is absolutely the best time to use arrays  - All of that repeated code would become a simple loop.  And you would only need a single `IBAction` method too

Comment: you HAVE TO name your vars, functions (including IBActions) with a lowercase letter as the first character

Comment: @Paulw11 How would you recommend using the arrays? Kind of new to Swift (As we all kind of are. :)

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus I've always thought that was kind of personal preference, what would happen if I didn't?

Comment: Put all of of those `BlackTiles` and `WhiteTiles` into two arrays - You can do this straight from IB using a referencing outlet collection instead of a referencing outlet.  Then all of those `+142` lines can be a loop.  The second bit of code, you check for the blacktile > 600 if so then reset it plus the appropriate white tiles - These are blacktileindex*2, blacktileIndex*2+1 and blacktileIndex*2+2 (remember arrays have a 0 index).  This is nothing to do with Swift, it is just basic coding.

Comment: You don't have to use lowercase for variables, but it is a very strong convention - it makes code more readable

Comment: @Paulw11 talking like this you are almost saying it is ok if you want

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the help! Never really thought of indexing an array of objects before, I'll be sure to fix that later today. :)

Comment: I am not saying it is OK, I am saying that code will still run if you flout the convention.

Comment: @user3842758 I think you should read the book before starting any code.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11

Comment: after reading the basics you can go forward and read how to use it with cocoa

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/using-swift-cocoa-objective/id888894773?mt=11

Comment: there you will find some loop examples as well

Comment: Also I am not sure what this syntax is supposed to be doing ` [RandomPlacementThree()]` - Seems to be some hybrid of Objective-C and Swift, the [] are unnecessary - again if you had an array then you could pass an index to a single random function and have it do the right things

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Have read the book already, I know how to program, been programming for about 4 years now. I'm still learning more and more, and I come on sites like this to look for the best answers. I've know about the lowercase letter first, but was just rushing through this, and didn't think to do it. I know the code will still run fine either way, but it is definitely better to have the lowercase first.Thanks for all the help. :)

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh! I meant to fix that! Thanks for the reminder. :)

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Any Idea why the buttons wouldn't move? Thanks for all the book recommendations too, didn't realize there was a book about using Swift with Objective - C, this is going to help me with a project I'm working on right now. Thanks!

Comment: @ user3842758 You are welcome. If you zip your whole project folder I can take a look at it.

Comment: don't forget to rename it all first :)

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Haha, will do. :)

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmwu5ax6l8qex5j/WhiteTiles%202.zip?dl=0

Comment: BTW that include those IBOutlet vars

Comment: It is a really weird behavior if you just update the score with a constant value it works and as soon you change it to the counter it stops working

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Haha, didn't want to change everything, that would've taken longer, just want to get this done. I'll change later.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Yeah, I noticed that too, something wrong just happens as soon as you change that value. So confusing.

Comment: I did change it for you but the behavior I really can't explain why a constant string works

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7q0udxqnqqnm15g/WhiteTiles.zip?dl=0

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Ah well, thanks for the suggestions and all the help! I'll try to figure it out. Have a wonderful day. :)